# NodeJS blessed no key events

Tags: node.js, blessed

I am new to using the blessed library and so far, I could not get key events to work.

I would expect the following piece of code to print `q` whenever the Q key is pressed and `Enter` whenever the Enter key is pressed. It should also print `keypress` whenever any key is pressed.

```js
const blessed = require('blessed');

const screen = blessed.screen({
    smartCSR: true,
    title: 'Title',
});

screen.key('q', () => console.log('q'));
screen.key('Enter', () => console.log('Enter'));

screen.on('keypress', () => console.log('keypress'));

screen.render();
```

The actual behavior is that if any "printable" key (such as alphanumeric characters) is pressed then that key is just written to the console (just as if it was typed regularly). `keypress` is not printed either.

The behavior is slightly different for the Enter key. `Enter` is still not being printed, but `keypress` is.

Is there anything wrong with my setup? I am using the default Gnome terminal under ArchLinux. However, that should not cause an issue because the program [json-log-viewer](https://github.com/gistia/json-log-viewer), which is also blessed-based, works just fine.

Comment: Blessed is a good library but unfortunately it's not maintained. The repo should be archived. `terminal-kit` is maintained and has many APIs but it has terrible documentations. I was trying to write TUI in JS and I gave up eventually.

Comment: Yeah that's probably true. Even after I got the key events to work they are still very slow (holding down a key feels incredibly laggy). I'll also give terminal-kit a try and see how that works. Another interesting library should be [ink](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink) which promises to bring React to the terminal.

Comment: I personally didn't have any problems with key bindings (I used node readline for key event handling). I was trying to make a ncurses-like interface and the app needed modals. I encountered various issues. I wrote the app by using electron eventually. TUI wasn't a good option for my case. Blessed is unmaintained, but it's still a good library and terminal-kit has many useful APIs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with `nodemon`, fixed by passing the flag `-I`. See [here](https://github.com/chjj/blessed/issues/334).

Comment: Holy crap.  I know there's not a need for gratitude comments, but you saved me, and taught me something new.  

Adding a bit of knowledge I came across to reload your app state on restart: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#gracefully-reloading-down-your-script